# If you { turned / would turn } down the volume of the TV, that would be great

Tags: subjunctives

> 1. If you turned down the volume of the TV, that would be great.
> 2. If you would turn down the volume of the TV, that would be great.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?
What difference is there in their meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I  would  say that both examples are grammatical and I guess your concern has something to do with the use of **would** in if-clauses. If so keep in mind that in polite requests [would](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/will_would_if_clauses.htm) is possible in if-clauses.

Regarding the meaning, your both examples convey the same idea, yet the second example is more polite.

Answer (score 1):

The first one stick to the **second conditional** form, the second doesn't.

If you want to have the second one with the second conditional form, you can use *could*:

> *If you could turn down the volume of the TV, that would be great.*
>   (I can't do it, so it's not great.)

This works since it sticks with the *if + past simple* in the main clause as *could* being the past simple of *can.*

---

Now if you want that the behaviour of something or something to be different, you can use *if only + would + base form*:

> *If only you would turn down the volume of the TV.*

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct, and just a little awkward. Consider the following versions:

> If you could turn down the volume, that would be great.

...

> "Mind turning down the volume a little?"
>   "Like, right now?"
>   "That would be great, thanks."

The TV part can be skipped. Think about it.

Comment: Usually the TV part can be skipped, although every now and then you'd want to leave it in: _Would you mind turning down the TV? I'm trying to hear the news on the radio._ (This example shows that sometimes you can omit the "volume" part, too.)

Comment: @J.R.: You can omit pretty much everything by saying, "Would you _please_?" They'll usually know what you're talking about.